# how does ! effect sort in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I am trying to sort the contents in my text file using the command

```
:1,$sort
```

This results in lines arranged in order based on the starting character - symbols, capital letters and then small letters

Now if i use

```
:1,$!sort
```

I get a different order which does not seem to make any sense. Everything looks mixed up.

So what is the role of the `!` command here? Why does it mess up the entire sorting behaviour?According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118/2105986, it is supposed to be a filter operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` character in the `vi` command mode causes vi to use the external application [`sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sort.1.html) to sort the lines.

Your first command `:1,$sort` causes `vi` to use it's internal sort mechanism. In your second command `:1,$!sort` all lines are taken and given as standard input to the application `sort`.

Just try this `vi` command: `:!ls -la`. You will see the output of `ls` and after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> you get back to `vi`. That mechanism is usually (for example) to compile the code written in `vi` without closing and reopening the file.

So you see, using `!` in this case causes complete different mechanisms. The ubuntu `sort` utility may sort different than the `vi` internal one.

Answer (score 1):

According to that answer, `1,$!sort` is the **ex**-mode version. You enter ex-mode by typing `Q` in normal mode. The normal mode version of this command is `1G!Gsort` according to that SO answer. Otherwise, as chaos says, `!` causes vim to open a shell and execute `sort` in it (thereby calling the `sort` program).